# Android Callback function from Java to Webview Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I am trying to implement a simple callback to call a function from Java to WebView. I successfully called the function from Javascript to Java but couldn't get any success for the otherway around.

Here's my **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    view= new WebView(this);
    setContentView(view);

    view.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/meter.html");
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

}

public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void register(String callback) {
        Log.e("work","log printing");   // <--- coming here
        view.loadUrl("javascript:callbacker('hola moma');");
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

And here's my **meter.html** file

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showAndroidToast(toast) {
            Android.register("callbacker");
        }
        function callbacker(data){
            Android.showToast(data);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

     <p>Display a gauge:</p>
    <meter value="2" min="0" max="10">2 out of 10</meter><br>
    <meter value="0.6">60%</meter>
     <input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> The &lt;meter&gt; tag is not supported in Internet Explorer, Edge 12, Safari 5 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
```

Now When I run the application the `Log` in the register function of MainActivity.java is printed. But the next line is which is just a call to the callback function is not called. What could be the problem ?

Comment: what you expect from this line ? `view.loadUrl("javascript:callbacker('hola moma');");`

Comment: i expect it to call the callbacker function defined in the html file